# É possível atribuir um valor diferente do valor adquirido de um OPTION em um SELECT quando for submeter o formulário para o PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, codeigniter

Bem, acredito que o título dessa pergunta tenha ficado confuso, mas tentarei detalhar melhor o meu problema.

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto com o framework CodeIgniter (sou iniciante) onde tenho uma página php/html com um formulário que contém alguns dados trazidos do banco para dentro de cada `<option>` de um `<select>`:

```
<select id="estado" name="estado">
   <option selected disabled hidden>Selecione um estado</option>
      <?php foreach($estados as $uf): ?>

       <option value="<?php echo $uf->id_estado ?>">
            <?php echo $uf->estado ?></option>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

      <br><br>


<select id="cidade" name="cidade">
   <option selected disabled hidden>Selecione uma cidade</option>

   <?php foreach($cidades as $cid): ?>

      <option value="<?php echo $cid->id_estado ?>">
         <?php echo $cid->cidade ?></option>

   <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

No `<select>` do estado o value é preenchido com o id do estado e o conteúdo com o nome do estado.

No `<select>` da cidade o value é preenchido com a chave estrangeira referente ao estado em que a cidade pertence e o conteúdo com o nome da cidade.

O problema é que preciso passar o id da cidade quando for submeter o formulário ao invés da chave estrangeira. Passei a chave no lugar do id justamente para que as cidades a serem exibidas sejam apenas aquelas pertencentes ao estado selecionado anteriormente.

Este é o código Javascript/Jquery responsável por controlar a exibição:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#estado").change(function () {

 // a cidade inicia selecionado em "SELECIONE UMA CIDADE"
        $("#cidade").val($("#cidade option:first").val());

        var estado = document.getElementById("estado").value;
        var cidade = document.getElementById("cidade");

   for(var i = 0; i < cidade.length; i++){         
 /* se a chave estrangeira tiver o mesmo valor que o id do estado
  selecionado a opção será exibida, caso contrário a opção não aparecerá.*/

        if(cidade.options[i].value == estado){
            cidade.options[i].style.display = 'block';
        }

        else{
            cidade.options[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
        }).change();
});
```

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível passar o id da cidade para o formulário sem que afete a exibição desses elementos equivalentes ou se há uma forma mais prática de mostrar esses dados e me permita enviar o id correto.

Agradeço desde já quem puder me auxiliar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a melhor opção seja armazenar os ids do estado no atributo `dataset`, ao invés do `value`.

```
echo "<option value='{$cid->id_cidade}' data-id_estado='{$cid->id_estado}'>{$cid->cidade}</option>"
```

Dessa forma você pode recuperar a informação com o atributo `dataset` usando a chave declarada, nesse caso, `id_estado`

```
    if(cidade.options[i].dataset.id_estado == estado){
        cidade.options[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else{
        cidade.options[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
```